# How to make a Secret iOS App text animation in Android?

Tags: android, animation, text, app-secret

I'm looking for a way to replicate the behaviour of text animation in the iOS Secret app to Android. the effect is describe in the following question:

[How to Make a Secret iOS App Text Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23048731/how-to-make-a-secret-ios-app-text-animation/23048955#23048955)

And you could also see it implemented for iOS here:

https://github.com/rcmcastro/RQShineLabel

Does anyone familiar with a similar library for the Android framework? Or know how to implement same effect in Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this library that allows to add different animations to a `TextView` and did the trick for me:

https://github.com/hanks-zyh/HTextView

This is the staff you can add using it:

[image]

All you have to do to animate the text is:
Choose the type of the animation you want to use:

```
mHTextView.setAnimateType(HTextViewType.EVAPORATE);
```

And run an animation on newly added text:

```
mHTextView.animateText("String text");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this but this lib is not available with gradle
https://github.com/matthewrkula/SecretTextView

Comment: Thanks for the link, don't know why I didn't find it then. Please copy the relevant code parts from the readme file into your answer for future SO users.